# how to covert the file in to pandas dataframe with same format in the input

Tags: python, pandas

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5Gjh.png)]

The format is not same as the input it is jumbeled

what is the code after reading a file how to convert to pandas data frame with the same format